# Did we entangle the qubits in phase estimation algorithm?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, hamiltonian-simulation, quantum-phase-estimation

This is a follow-up question to my [earlier post](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/24156/15562) about the phase estimation algorithms. From the Qiskit tutorials of [QPE](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-algorithms/quantum-phase-estimation.html) and [IPE](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-labs/Lab04_IterativePhaseEstimation.html#2-iterative-phase-estimation-ipe-algorithm), the qubit $q_1$ represents the physical system on which $U$ operates remains on the same quantum state, provided that it is initialized to an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian we're simulating. Meanwhile, $q_0$ (the auxiliary qubit) and $q_1$ are not entangled. However, if we prepare the initial state of $q_1$ to be a superposition of eigenstates, will the two qubits be entangled? In this case when we perform a measurement in $_0$, are we 'projecting' the quantum state on $_1 $ onto a subspace associated with the measurement outcome?

Here's an example of IPE circuit:

[image]

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Simply put: Yes!

Comment: @DaftWullie Thanks, could you give me some hint why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of phase estimation is that for some eigenvector $|u_s\rangle$, we learn the eigenvalue $s$, i.e.
$$
|0\rangle|u_s\rangle\rightarrow |s\rangle|u_s\rangle.
$$
So, now imagine we input a superposition
$$
|0\rangle(|u_s\rangle+|u_t\rangle).
$$
By linearity, the outcome must be
$$
|s\rangle|u_s\rangle+|t\rangle|u_t\rangle.
$$
Clearly this is entangled between the two registers. If you prefer to see it via a density matrix, trace out the second register. You know that $\langle u_s|u_t\rangle=0$ since eigenvectors form an orthonormal basis. Hence, the result is
$$
|s\rangle\langle s|+|t\rangle\langle t|.
$$
Since this is not pure (i.e. mixed), the original state must be entangled.

If I now measure the outcome state on the first register, I must get one of the two outcomes, chosen at random:
$$
|s\rangle|u_s\rangle,\qquad |t\rangle|u_t\rangle,
$$
thereby projecting onto one of the eigenvectors in the original superposition (the probability of getting each outcome is determined by its weight in the input state).

Here, I've assumed that the eigenvalues exactly match the eigenvalues detected by the phase estimation. If it's not perfect, then the outcome is essentially the same,but ther's a bit more uncertainty. But I don't want to confuse the issue!